# How does an irc daemon like Charybdis work?

Tags: unix, server, chat, daemon, irc

I am pretty new to irc, and am poking around in it to try and understand it.

I am running CentOS 7 on a VM, and have installed charybdis-4.1.1 and atheme-7.2.10-r2, using this marvellous [guide](http://matthughes.io/setting-up-an-irc-server-with-charybdis-and-atheme-updated-for-2018/). However, while the guide does a fantastic job of telling me how to install it, it doesn’t really tell me how it works, which is kinda my aim of doing this.

What I had in mind was to set up a server and poke around it under the guidance of some online tutorial. However, I couldn’t really find any material online that explains how certain files work. I tried reading the documentation page on github, but it doesn’t really tell me how it works either.

I understand that most people use irc clients instead of actually installing and maintaining a server, which may be part of the reason why I couldn’t find any material. So….would any kind soul help in giving me a primer in how this works? Or perhaps provide a link to some tutorial on charybdis? Thank you so much!!

Comment: You could try asking people in #charybdis on Freenode. The majority of IRCds still in use have downright ancient codebases spanning many forks, so I'd imagine most resources on their inner workings are either on some obscure part of the net or lost to time. Your best bet in general would likely be to find where the maintainers for a given IRCd hang out and ask questions there. This is actually a topic I've been interested in for some time but have yet to look into.

Comment: Some other places you could try: [UnrealIRCd dev channel](ircs://irc.unrealircd.org:6697/unreal-devel), [InspIRCd dev channel](ircs://irc.inspircd.org:+6697/#inspircd.dev), or even just reading the various RFCs for IRC will give you a better idea of how things should work. [This site](https://ircv3.net/) has various documentation as well as links to aforementioned RFCs.

Comment: #ircd-coders on irc.ircd-hybrid.org is yet another place you could try.